# Translating modules

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

How do I translate drupal modules, or download existing translations?
I downloaded the translation from https://localize.drupal.org/ but not everything is translated.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to translate. At the first you should enable the Content translation and Locale modules.

- You can download your translates from [Drupal localize](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=) and you can search for your modules translates.
- You can download and install the [Localization update](https://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module. This module automatically installs the module translations when you install a new module.
- You can install the [Localization client](https://drupal.org/project/l10n_client) module, which helps you to translate and save your own translates in your site.
- You can translate the strings of your site manually in admin/config/regional/translate/translate.

Answer (score 3):

try to look at this url it's very useful for u 
http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/localized-and-multi-lingual-content-drupal-7